# Why does a black box appear instead of my icon python tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, icons, tk-toolkit

I'm still a beginner and I'm working on a window using tkinter in pygame. I tried replacing the tk logo with a transparent one and I got the image there, but it's just a black box, not the transparent one I had. I then replaced the square icon with a really thin rectangular one to make it nearly-invisible, but it's still the black box. By the way, the second icon I tried was 2 pixels in width by 864 in height. The first one was [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=transparent+icon&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1AVFC_enCA889CA889&sxsrf=ALeKk00bVby5ncjfFNmQw6aNfPSzRmNULw:1599100041504&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYjrzv98vrAhVDiFkKHXoDA7YQ_AUoAXoECBcQAw&biw=1920&bih=1009#imgrc=fOPHqTlQPBm_AM). Here's my script:

````
from tkinter import *

#These are all my variables. You can change anything in here and it should work just fine, but don't change the data types.
name = "Project"
bg_color = "crimson"
width = 800
height = 600
min_width = 540
min_height = 420

class Win:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.wm_minsize(min_width, min_height) #This sets the minsize (smallest you can make a window) for my window
        self.root.configure(background=bg_color) #This sets the background color of my window
        self.root.iconphoto(False, PhotoImage(file="images/icon.png")) #I made a seperate file for my icon image, but you don't have to.
        self.root.title(name) #This sets my window's title
        self.root.geometry(str(width) + "x" + str(height)) #This sets my window's size
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Win(Tk()).root.title(name)
    tk = Tk()
    Tk().mainloop()```
````

Comment: After changing the code block under `if __name__ == "__main__"` to `Win(Tk())` only, the code works fine in my Python 3.8.5 environment in Windows 7.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating three instances of `Tk`. You should only ever create one.

Comment: Ive added an answer